# Picker layout changed when you apply a renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

Why is Picker's layout being so altered when I apply a custom renderer?

layout after applying Renderer:
[image]

How to leave the original layout but applying a custom renderer?

And also the confirm button are not showing up anymore. They are white, if you click where they should be they work.

Custom Renderer:

```
public class MyPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var spinner = new Spinner(this.Context);

            Control.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent.ToAndroid());
            Control.InputType = InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions;
            Control.SetTextColor(Color.Red.ToAndroid());

            spinner.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red.ToAndroid());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We need see the rederer's source code to help with it.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Reload please

Comment: Are you inheriting the XF default PickerRenderer constructors?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Yes, reload again please.

Comment: On it's source code the view set the picker's layout in the `OnClick` method, that is called by the `OnFocusChangeRequested` method, but it's internal... Take a look at the [default renderer source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/PickerRenderer.cs), maybe it can help you. I couln't see any explanation

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and found the solution is this: 
Make sure you are using **Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer** not 
 **Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PickerRenderer**

Answer from here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100317/custom-renderer-for-picker-automatically-changes-layout-in-app-without-overrides